# Android Phonegap and JQueryMobile Integration

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying to find a answer to this hopefully you guys can help out.
I recently got Phonegap working in eclipse for my android programming, I want to get jquerymobile integrated with phonegap for the UI.

Could anyone tell if there is anything special I need to do to get Jquerymobile to work with eclipse and Phonegap.

Or direct me to a decent tutorial/article.

I'm not seeing alot of JQuery Documentation regarding this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special other than including the required .js files.  Just be careful though, the jquery mobile ui will slowed the app a lot.